# Unsupervised text classification

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've built a spam mail classifier using Python 3 and sklearn. For spam/ham classification, I've used Support Vector Machine, which has a pretty good accuracy(~99%)

The problem I'm facing now is, once I've classified ham mails, I want to automatically categorize them eg: mail related to politics, mailed related to music and so on and put them into their specific bucket.

The challenge is I cannot train the algorithm with mails of specific kind since I don't know what sort of mail might land up in my inbox, so I'm stuck at this stage. If anyone can share some workaround it'd be great. Thanks.

Comment: I"m not sure what you're asking of your system.  It sounds as if you want it to magically determine category breadth for you, assign the labels, and partition the emails.  Magic is fine -- we're the magicians.  However, the result has to be feasible within information theory.  How is this supposed to know that a reference to "Dead Kennedys Stealing People's Mail" is a reference to a punk rock band, rather than politics and information security?  Is the category "Music", "Punk/Rock", or something more specific?

Answer (score 2):

You can look at [Latent Dirichlet allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) ([topic modelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model) technique).
But this model will return unlabeled groups of emails.